# The instance of entity type 'X' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'X'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I think the problem is due to an incompatibility on the class side. But I didn't fully understand.

The Error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'JoinCartSelection' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CartId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Class:

```
public class JoinCartSelection : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public int SelectionValueId { get; set; }
    public int? Piece { get; set; }

    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public virtual SelectionValue SelectionValue { get; set; }

    public void Build(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<JoinCartSelection>(entity =>
        {
            entity
            .HasKey(p => p.CartId);

            entity
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.CartId, p.SelectionValueId });

            entity
            .HasOne(p => p.Cart)
            .WithMany(p => p.JoinCartSelections)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CartId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity
           .HasOne(p => p.SelectionValue)
           .WithMany(p => p.JoinCartSelections)
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.SelectionValueId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        });
    }
}
```

Controller Error Part:

```
if (cart.MultipleSelection != null)
        {
            var multiples = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (var selecton in cart.MultipleSelection)
            {
                string[] slc = selecton.Split(",");

                multiples.Add(Convert.ToInt32(slc[0]), Convert.ToInt32(slc[1]));
            }

            foreach (var mt in multiples)
            {
                var jcs = new JoinCartSelection
                {
                    SelectionValueId = mt.Key,
                    Piece = mt.Value

                };
                cart.JoinCartSelections.Add(jcs);
                appDbContext.Entry(jcs).State = EntityState.Added;
            }

        }

        await appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        TempData["successAddCart"] = "Sepete Eklendi";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: Is `appDbContext` used anywhere else? How `cart.MultipleSelection` is populated?

Comment: `.HasKey(p => p.CartId)` means `CartId` is unique (no duplicate values). `.HasOne(p => p.Cart).WithMany(p => p.JoinCartSelections).HasForeignKey(p => p.CartId)` means `CartId` allow duplicate values. These two conflict, and  the result is one-to-one relationship, hence the exception. You probably need to make PK composite like the index you are creating, e.g. remove `[Key]` attribute, remove `HasKey` and `HasIndex` and add `.HasKey(p => new { p.CartId, p.SelectionValueId })`.

Comment: dear Ivan, I have been dealing with this problem for days. First of all, your troubleshooting was very good and very descriptive. I applied the solution as you said and my problem was solved. Thank you so much.